# Is I/O error sufficient reason to return SSD on warranty?

Tags: linux, ssd, io, hard-drive-failure

Several times I’ve encountered heavy disk errors leading to complete system crash, after reboot m/b doesn’t detect SSD till full PC poweroff.

Here is log I've managed to display before OS gone completely down:

[image]

`sdg` is OS SSD drive. I wonder if it qualifies for warranty and if it’d be accepted. It’s a Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256gb and has been used only for half a year and 5TB written.

Comment: You have to go to the people who sold it to you.

Comment: Do i need to prove anything when I return drive or explain when it fails? I must say that I've never returned any drive on warranty.

Comment: See my comment above.